# Have there been successful class action lawsuits due to infosec breaches?

Tags: legal, incident-response

Whenever there is a major security breach affecting consumers, often large costs are quoted (e.g. [35 million for TalkTalk](http://www.cyber-riskinsure.co.uk/talktalk-cyber-breach-to-cost-35m/)). One reason given for these large costs is the potential for affected people to sue the company.

Have there been cases of people successfully sueing, or getting a settlement? I'm particularly asking about consumers sueing a company; I presume company-to-company legal action is common but shrouded in secrecy. Hence asking about "class action" - or the equivalent in other jurisdictions.

Comment: I had to think of [Should we be more strict about legal questions](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/1935/should-we-be-more-strict-about-legal-questions)

Comment: Propabaly should be migrated to http://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Stephane The question actually doesn't call for a legal conclusion, just whether there's been any lawsuits.  I think it's far more likely that people here would know this than in the law site.  You'd have to be a lawyer dedicated to computing to know those specifics.

Comment: I've found [another question](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41324/what-are-some-examples-of-legal-action-taken-as-the-result-of-a-security-breach?rq=1) but still interested in further info

Comment: Google "class action lawsuit data breach" and I get a list of active class action law suits (from lawyers, etc).

Comment: @schroeder - thanks using "data breach" does help (I shoulda thought of that!) But it tends to flag up pending lawsuits, not resolved ones - and this question is about resolved ones.

Comment: I just love it when my vote is the last one to open a question and I get it re-opened :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and a high profile one was Sony's PSN breach which Sony settled for $15million, [one report here](http://ps4daily.com/2014/07/sony-settles-psn-hack-lawsuit/).

Though the headline figure does not appear as bad when you realise that it is not an actual pay out, it is mainly free games and memberships for those affected.

*From a purely UK specific perspective related to the Data Protection Act (DPA) compensation:*

*In terms of risk management decisions and the potential legal cost of a breach (and its part in deciding appropriate security measures) there was an interesting decision made in the court of appeal earlier this year in the on-going Hall v Google case...*

[Court of Appeal judgement](https://www.judiciary.gov.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/google-v-vidal-hall-judgment.pdf)

*The DPA rules for compensation are such that compensation for distress can only be pursued where actual losses have been incurred i.e. distress in isolation does not entitle compensation. In the Hall v Google case the Court of Appeal decided that this aspect of the DPA was inconsistent with the EU legislation and was therefore not applicable, which could set a precedent depending on how the rest of the case plays out.*

*In my opinion this is something to keep an eye on because the implications are potentially huge!*

Comment: Just to say I was tempted to include something about UK legislation and the potential changing data protection compensation landscape, but it would be partly subjective (albeit with court of appeal references), hence the rather brief answer!

Comment: if you did have time to expand on that, I'd be interested.

Comment: @paj28 Obviously there is more to it than I have summarised but hopefully it makes the point I intend.

Answer (score 2):

LinkedIn settled for $1.5M for weak password protections

http://bits.blogs.nytimes.com/2015/02/23/linkedin-settles-class-action-suit-over-weak-password-security/?_r=0

Comment: Thanks... a pretty low amount per-customer, which is interesting!